# How to use what retoune my future in the rest demon code

Tags: flutter

my events from my database are not displayed
this my code

```
Future loadPreviousEvents() async {
    var url = 'http://prospection.global-aeit.com/getEvents.php';
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = json.decode(res.body) as List;
    var mySelectedEvents = response.groupBy<String, Map>(
      (item) => "${item['date']}",
      valueTransform: (item) => item..remove('date'),
    );
    return mySelectedEvents;
  }
```

how to use `return mySelectedEvents;` in the rest of the code

```
  List _listOfDayEvents(DateTime dateTime) {
    if (mySelectedEvents[DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateTime)] != null) {
      return mySelectedEvents[DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateTime)]!;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: check https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: it's don't help me

Comment: mySelectedEvents[DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateTime)] does not recognize return mySelectedEvents; from futur